# CGAffineTransform from two lines - each represented by a pair of CGPoints

Tags: objective-c, graphics, core-graphics, transform

You can probably see where I am going with this - but is there any **easy** way to generate a CGAffineTransform from two lines - each represented by a pair of CGPoints:

```
A[(a1x,a1y), (a2x,a2y)],
B[(b1x,b1y), (b2x,b2y)]
```

The resultant CGAffineTransform when applied to line A would of course produce line B. It potentially could involve a translation, scale, and rotation.

Certainly I would hope to be able to write this myself after brushing up on some trig but I was wondering if anything is already available to do this?

**Note:** I am not asking you to write this for me - I just don't want to miss a Core Graphics trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there are at least four solutions: two translations and two scales (one per operation and direction). That's without counting transformations that both translate *and* scale.

[“The Math Behind the Matrices”](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD), from the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/), is a good overview of how each operation works; from that, it should be simple enough to invert it and come up with a matrix for the desired operation and direction.

> Certainly I would hope to be able to write this myself after brushing up on some trig…

You won't need that except for rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the references. However, I think my question wasn't clear enough so I have revised it. The pairs of points each represent a line so a transformation between the two could involve a rotation.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, that seems possible. Scale is easy: divide lengthB by lengthA. Rotation: Take the angle of each line, then subtract one angle from the other. Translation: Take the lines' center points and subtract one from the other. The trickiest part will be putting them all together in the matrix in the correct order. Scale first, I *think*.